# Geometrical Parameters of Induction Motors

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, induction-motor

How does one relate the Thevenin equivalent circuit parameters of an induction motor to the physical geometry of the motor?

I am particularly looking for the transient torque of a single phase induction motor analysed within the context of Maxwell's equations if possible. The problem is that a superficial analysis of the torque vs speed yields a direct proportionality relation as expected, but it doesn't display the torque decrease to zero near synchronous speed.

Comment: Keep looking for graphs . They exist

Comment: I am looking for analysis in terms of rigorous electromagnetic theory, not a statement of results.

Comment: A book with the phrase "Electric Machines" in the title, or comprising the title then.  Or post your analysis and we'll point out where it's not correct.  You're probably not taking slip into account, or possibly losses.

Comment: The books I have come across just jump into Thevenin equivalents directly. I am looking for a direct physical explanation.